# Can't create Azure lock through rest api

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

Can't create azure lock for certain resource through rest api, how it says over here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/managementlocks/createorupdateatsubscriptionlevel
While requesting this url i got the following:
"The client  with object id  does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/locks/write'
Meantime i have in azure owner subscription, what can cause this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While requesting this url i got the following: "The client with object id does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/locks/write' Meantime i have in azure owner subscription, what can cause this problem?

It means that you have no permission to do that. I assume that you are using Azure AD application to get the acess token. If it is that case, please assign application to [owner role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role). Then it should work for you.

[image]

I test it with postman.

[image]