# Unable to set lock on SQL Server database

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have the following bicep to set a lock in my SQL Server database:

```
resource SqlDatabase_DeleteLock 'Microsoft.Authorization/locks@2020-05-01' = {
  scope: primaryDatabase
  name: 'Do Not Delete'
  properties: {
    level: 'CanNotDelete'
    notes: 'Created by SqlDatabase Bicep template deployment'
  }
}
```

On running this, I see this error:

> 'Authorization failed for template resource 'Do Not Delete' of type 'Microsoft.Authorization/locks'. The client 'xxx' with object id 'yyy' does not have permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/locks/write' at scope '/subscriptions/xyz/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/server/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/locks/Do Not Delete'

I can't add manually as well due to this error:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing "Authorization" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't create Azure lock through rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346422/cant-create-azure-lock-through-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicate the issue I am also having same issue

[image]

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1161367/configure-resource-lock-exercise-no-permission-to) It is related to subscription issue, you are not granted to Add/Edit the locks in your subscription. It will be available in paid/Azure Free subscriptions.

Regarding This error:

> 'Authorization failed for template resource 'Do Not Delete' of type 'Microsoft.Authorization/locks'. The client 'xxx' with object id 'yyy' does not have permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/locks/write' at scope '/subscriptions/xyz/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/server/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/locks/Do Not Delete'

It is related to authorization error. As @Tom Sun - MSFT Said assign owner role to the app. This may work:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a least role that works to add locks? Also, can this be applied to a resource level instead of subscription level?

Comment: You should have owner role to set locks and it can be applicable to resource level.

Comment: I see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/lock-resources?tabs=json#who-can-create-or-delete-locks To create or delete management locks, you need access to Microsoft.Authorization/* or Microsoft.Authorization/locks/* actions. I need to only CREATE lock NOT delete. What is needed for that?

Comment: To Create/Add lock you should have owner role.

Comment: I added a custom role containing action "Microsoft.Authorization/locks/*". on this resource group. Even then, I see the same error.